# iPhoneアプリをswiftで作成しています。LazyVGridで作成したのですが思う結果がでません。何か間違っているのかわかりません。

Tags: swift

コードは以下の通りです。

```
import SwiftUI
   let layout2: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(minimum: 40, maximum: 75)), count: 5)
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var scores: [Int] = [1,3,4,3,2,  2,3,3,4,3]
    var body: some View {
   //             Text("\(scores.count)")  = 10
  //      ScrollView {
  
            HStack {
                LazyVGrid(columns: layout2, spacing: 1) {
                    ForEach(scores, id: \.self) { num in
                        ZStack {
                            Rectangle()
                                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                                .frame(height: 45)
                            Text("\(num)")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        } // ZStack
                        
                    } // ForeEach
                } // LazyVGrid
            }  // HStack
//        }  // ScrollView
    }  // body
}  // ContentView

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: あなたにとっての「思う結果」が何かは読者にはわからないのです。こうなってほしかったんだけど、こうなってしまった。というような説明を追記していただけると回答できる人が増えそうな気がします。

Comment: このアプリは、パークゴルフのスコアを出力するイメージでつくったものです。出力は1ホール(一番左の出力)　3 4 3 2(スコア,画面では3が出ないで空白となっている)と出力、次に2ホール　3　3　4　2と2行になるつもりです。

Answer (score 1):

ログにエラーの内容が出ているはずです。

```
LazyVGridLayout: the ID 3 is used by multiple child views, this will give undefined results!
LazyVGridLayout: the ID 2 is used by multiple child views, this will give undefined results!
LazyVGridLayout: the ID 4 is used by multiple child views, this will give undefined results!
```

ForEachでは同じidのものを渡してはいけません。
ここではscoresのForEachでselfを渡しているため、被りがあります。それが原因です。

以下とかであれば綺麗に表示されると思います。

```swift
ForEach(1..<30, id: \.self) { num in
```

以下のようにScoreを設定して、scores: [Score]とすればうまくいくはずです。

```swift
struct Score {
  let id = UUID()
  let score: Int
}
```